# is there any way to invoke customized Aysnc callback function at clientside in GWT Application?

Tags: java, gwt

is there any way to invoke  customized Aysnc callback function at clientside in GWT Application?

As per my concern i need to call my customized callback function at client side instead of default AsyncCallback function..

is it possible.....

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do like this

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface MycustomisedCallBack extends AsyncCallback<T> {


   @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught);
   @Override
    public void onSuccess(T result);

    public void onmyMethod();
}
```

And pass your  `MycustomisedCallBack` to RPC.

```
rpcService.rpcMethod(new MycustomisedCallBack() {

            @Override
            public void onmyMethod() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(T result) {

            };
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to create your own customized AsyncCallback class, for example:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public class MyAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {

    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
        // default onFailure method, invoking your method
        myOnFailure(arg0);
    }

    private void myOnFailure(Throwable arg0) {
        // Your code here
    }

    public void onSuccess(T arg0) {
        // default onSuccess method invoking your method
        myOnSuccess (arg0);
    }

    private void myOnSuccess(T arg0) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

This class will receive any result type from the service being invoked, delegating the calls for onSuccess and onFailure method to your own methods (myOnSuccess and myOnFailure) where you can put your code.

The next step is to use your new MyAsyncCallback class to invoke rpc services. For example:

```
myService.sendString("foo", new MyAsyncCallback<String>());
```

In this example, the method being invoked (sendString) receives a String, and your customized methods must handle the proper Type handling if you want to build a generic callback manager.  Note also, that you don't need to implement the callback methods at the time of making the invocation.